# vertical scroll bar is not visible in windows phone while using phone:webBrowser?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

```
<ScrollViewer>
<phone:WebBrowser 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="browser"
    IsScriptEnabled="True" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I was initialized webBrowser like above. And I have made vertical scrollbar scripts as much i know. Still, Vertical scroll bar is not visible in webBrowser ?

What mistake I have done ?

Comment: Are you trying on emulator? Have you tried running on physical device?

Comment: I have tried on both. no vertical scroll bar

Comment: Have you tried setting the visibility-property on the ScrollViewer itself? `<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">...</ScrollViewer>`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a theme issue.

Your WebBrowser is loading HTML that has a white background, but the default color of the scroll bar is white. So, it may actually be there.

Try switching your device/emulator theme from dark to light. Then view the WebBrowser.